# Has the Key House set been used in another Sci-Fi show?

Tags: production, locke-and-key

I've just started watching Locke & Key and a number of the internal sets used for Key House seem very familiar, but I can't recall what show I've seen them in before.

The Hallway and Study in particular are ringing bells, and possibly the Kitchen/Dinner though that doesn't resonate as strongly. A long list of images is available [here](https://hookedonhouses.net/2020/02/18/keyhouse-locke-and-key-mansion-netflix/), but I've pulled out the two I've mentioned into the Question.

[image: Entrance Hall]

[image: Winter Study]

Comment: Instantly made me think of _Narnia_ but [it is not the same](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/75/29/8b/75298b545cf3f7c3a4c4e3a3b55e096b.png).

Comment: It made me think of The Umbrella Academy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Signs point to no. The set itself [doesn't exist in its entirety](https://www.newsweek.com/locke-key-netflix-locations-keyhouse-real-key-house-location-canada-toronto-1490022), but rather it was cobbled together using a mixture of CGI, set fragments (corners and edges) and composited together using editing techniques.

> Unfortunately for Locke and Key fans who want to take a visit to the real-life Keyhouse, it is one of the fake locations, recreated in multiple places that are made to look like one using some camera and computer magic.
>
> The exteriors were shot outside of Toronto, Canada, where part of the house was constructed as a facade, which was then completed using CGI. **Though the makers of Locke and Key have not revealed exactly how much of the Keyhouse was actually built, stills from the filming of the Netflix show reveal that at least the front doorway of the mansion was actually constructed.**
>
> **As for the interiors of the Keyhouse, they were actually built in the Cinespace Film Studios in Toronto, Canada.**
>
> <sub><sup>['LOCKE AND KEY' ON NETFLIX LOCATIONS: IS THE KEYHOUSE REAL?](https://www.newsweek.com/locke-key-netflix-locations-keyhouse-real-key-house-location-canada-toronto-1490022)</sup></sub>

It would also appear that the interiors were built exclusively for the series, although I'm sure some elements (fixtures, fittings, furniture, etc) will have been re-used from other shows made by the same company.

> For Cuse, the Lockes' house was a definitive part of the world of the story. But the version they made for the television series had to be workable as a television set. "When we adapted it for production, we had to make it really functional and practical. So the layout of the rooms, it was important to create these traffic patterns, these circularities so you could actually follow the characters. It was certainly something practical I learned on the Psycho house in Bates Motel, just kind of thinking how you move actors from space to space.
>
> "We sort of replicated that idea. We built the exterior of the house in Toronto. And then **we built the interior and we wanted to make sure the way the rooms were laid out on stage allowed for the characters to move easily [within] the various spaces.** The essence of it all came from Gabriel's design. The emotional goal was to make it feel inviting... there are a lot of incredible details in Keyhouse that will pay off down the stream."
>
> <sub><sup>[Locke & Key Artist Gabriel Rodriguez Reveals How He Designed Keyhouse](https://www.cbr.com/locke-key-comic-artist-gabriel-rodriguez-keyhouse-design/)</sup></sub>